# Is there a way to select rows in a Google Slides table using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, selection, google-slides

When the user runs a custom function, I want to be able to select the entire row of a table if the user's current selection is a textRange within that table.

I can manually select multiple cells in Google Slides by holding CTRL and clicking in each table cell, and that is the result I would like to get with the script function.

In Apps Script however, I only see options to select the entire table using pageElement.Select() or an individual textRange with textRange.select()